# Javascript: Simple currency converter with previous conversions

Tags: javascript, converters, currency

what i aim to do is a very simple currency converter. Basically, you type in a number, and press a button, a text is displayed that says "x dollars is y euros". Press the button again, a new text is displayed where the old one was, and the old one is displayed under the new one.

I've come so far that when something is entered in the field, it pops up below, and if you press the button again (with the same or a different value) it becomes a list of text.

To clarify what it is i'm saying here, take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8KAS/5/

Now i want to make it so that only numbers work, and so that number(x) is converted when the button is pressed and displayed below next to some fitting text (like "x dollars is y euros")

This is my js code, check the jsfiddle full code (html, js, css)

Any suggestions?

```
var count = 0;

function validate() {

   var amount = document.querySelector("#amount");

   if(amount.value.length > 0) {
       amount.className = 'correct';
   }

   else {
    amount.className = 'empty';
   }

   if (document.querySelector('.empty')) {
    alert('Något är fel');
   }

   else {
   addconvert(amount.value);
   }    
}

function addconvert(amount) {

   var table = document.querySelector('#tbody');
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var amountTd = document.createElement('td');


   var amountTextNode = document.createTextNode(amount);

   amountTd.appendChild(amountTextNode)
   tr.appendChild(amountTd);

   table.insertBefore(tr, table.firstChild);

   count++;     
}



var button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.onclick = validate;
```

Comment: So are you asking just how to check to see if a string is a valid number?

Comment: do you only want to convert dollar to euros ? can you put a static example of what you want the result to look like

Comment: yes, i only want to convert dollars to euros, very simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number validation is failing. Change the first part of your validation to this:

```
 function validate() {

    var amount = document.querySelector("#amount");
    var amountNum = parseFloat(amount.value);  //This is the numeric value, use it for calculations

    if(amount.value.length > 0 && !isNaN(amountNum) ) {
        amount.className = 'correct';
        amount.value = amountNum;
    }
    ...
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/w8KAS/6/

Cheers

Comment: isNaN = "is Not a Number". Wouldn't what you just wrote say some thing like this: If the length of "amount" is larger than 0 AND is not a number, run this (:amount.className etc...) I want it to require to be number. Also thanks for the reply

Comment: That's why it has the `!` before `isNaN`, so `!isNaN` = "is number" (double  logical negation)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I got this to work thanks to you, so thanks alot!

Comment: Welcome :). I advise you to learn jQuery, all this is so easy with jQuery ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a conversion rate (there are [APIs](https://openexchangerates.org/) for that), and then you can just add them together in a string

```
var convRate = 1.3; 
var amountTextNode = document.createTextNode(amount + " dollars is " + amount*convRate + " euros");
```

Regarding the API, Yahoo will tell you what you need without even the need to sign-in

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback="
}).done(function(data) { 
  convRate = data.query.results.rate.Rate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that only numbers work, you can test the variable `amount.value` using the `isNaN` function.  This will return true if the user's input is Not-a-Number, so if it returns false, you can proceed with your conversion.

```
if (!isNaN(amount.value)){
  addconvert(+amount.value)  // the plus symbol converts to a number
} else {
  // display error here
}
```

Inside your `addconvert` function, you can add code to will multiply your input amount by an exchange rate to get a rough conversion.

```
function addconvert(){
  // ...

  var euros = 0.74 * amount
  var text = amount + ' dollars is ' + euros + ' euros'
  var amountTextNode = document.createTextNode(text);
```